# Database structure for customers

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm building an app with parse as backend database. Maybe you guys can give me an advice for my database structure.

The customer gets registered. I have one table with some columns for the user data. After the registration a customer should create his own users (user data, bills etc). How can I combine these two tables with a good database structure?

I thought maybe to create 1 table with all user data from all customers and to create two columns (1 in customer table and the second one in Users table) with a unique id to shortcut the data to the correct customer. But maybe then u have a lot of data this solution will be slow because the app must query trough all data.

Second solution maybe to create for every customers a table with the user data. I think that would be much faster than the first one but I think maybe this will take many resources of the server or not then you have many customers?

I hope you have some good advice for me! Thank you

Comment: I'd with a single User class which has a pointer field to the Customer class. If you create an index in the User class to this field, you should not have any performance problem to retrieve a customer's users.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need 2 Classes here.  You can use the default _User class to store all this information in a single class.  You might have a Product and Purchases classes that are linked to _User in the future.